# Deadlifting with an extended spine

Tags: deadlifts, spine

Some people  say one should deadlift with a neutral spine, other says slightly flexed spine is okay too, but what about an extended spine?

When I deadlift, I notice a slight arch coming in back before the pull.

How does this compare with the other two?